# How to generate a random number , the length of the number needs to be 21 and should be prefixed with "01" in Postman

Tags: javascript, postman

I am using the code below to generate a random number. Result output should be a length of 21 and with prefix starting with "01"

```
postman.setGlobalVariable('RandomOrderId', "01"+ Math.floor(Math.random() * 1234567890123456789));
```

However, sometimes it generates output with a length of 20, 19 and so on. How do I make sure it always generate a random number with length 21 and prefix as "01"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below

```
postman.setGlobalVariable('RandomOrderId', "01"+ Math.floor(1000000000000000000 + Math.random() * 1000000000000000000));
```

Verify using the below

```js
function getRandomInt() {
  return ( "01" + Math.floor(1000000000000000000 + Math.random() * 1000000000000000000));
}

console.log(getRandomInt());
console.log(getRandomInt());
console.log(getRandomInt());
console.log(getRandomInt());
console.log(getRandomInt());
```

Comment: This isnt a random number with 21 digits, as it will always start with either 1 or 2 and only contains the values in between.

Comment: @WhiteMaple : The OP's requirement was that the number should start with "01" and 21 digits in length.

Comment: I am reading the word "random" in the question and the title. Therefore i guessed OP wants a random number.

Answer (score 1):

Math.random gives you a random number between 0 and 1, multiplying that with a million gives you something between zero and a million. If you want to allow leading numbers you could convert the number to a string and add the necessary amount of leading zeroes, if that is possible in your case. Else, you could generate 21 random numbers between 0 and 9 and combine them to a random huge number (which could also have leading zeroes).

Code could look like this:

```js
var s = "01";
    for(var i = 0; i < 21; i++) {
        s = s + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    }
    console.log(s);
```

Comment: Can you provide an example with some code?  What you are describing sounds very inefficient..would love to take a look!  Thanks

Comment: @JKimbrough There you go.

Answer (score 0):

Try injecting this JS:

```
var len = 21;
parseInt((Math.random() * 20 + 1) * Math.pow(20,len-1), 20);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the `Lodash` [_.random()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#random) method within Postman. Set the lower and upper values for the range and it will return a 19 digit number between those values. The `01` prefix can be added straight to the global value.

```
const lowerLimit = 1000000000000000000
const upperLimit = 9999999999999999999

pm.globals.set("randomNumber", `01${_.random(lowerLimit,upperLimit)}`)
```

Just a different way to get the same result as the accepted answer.